# Matches lasts non-words with last word on string

Tags: php, html, regex, string

I need matches the *lasts non-words* with *last word* on string (*both optionals*). The matches will be removed from original string by replacing it by null. My current results are:

**Regular expression:**

```
\W*  # Matches optional lasts non-words.
\w*  # Matches optional last word.
$
```

**Working cases:** [unit tests here](https://regex101.com/r/rI8nM9/1)

```
String                        Removed            Result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"Hello World!"                "!"                "Hello World"
"Hello World"                 " World"           "Hello"
"Hello "                      " "                "Hello"
"Hello"                       "Hello"            ""

"Hello; World!"               "!"                "Hello; World"
"Hello; World"                "; World"          "Hello"
"Hello;"                      ";"                "Hello"
```

---

Of course, I'm having a problem. I want accept HTML entities as part of the word, but as it have non-words characters (the ending *semicolon*), it final semicolon is matched and replaced incorrectly.

Currently I expects only that is matches simple HTML entities, basically it `&\w+;` (like `&aaccute;`), I'll improve it later (*for now, let uses it to simplify answer*).

**What I expect:** [unit tests here, failing for now](https://regex101.com/r/pH7tK2/1)

```
String                        Removed            Result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"Hell&aaccute; World!"        "!"                "Hell&aaccute; World"
"Hell&aaccute; World"         " World"           "Hell&aaccute;"
"Hell&aaccute;"               "Hell&aaccute;"    ""
"&aaccute; &aaccute;"         " &aaccute;"       "&aaccute;"
"&aaccute; "                  " "                "&aaccute;"
"&aaccute;"                   "&aaccute;"        ""
```

---

I just need add the HTML entities expression in some place to avoid matches it on first expression (`\W*`), I guess. But I tried somethings and it does not worked.

Comment: It is probably an easy task, but the main problem is to define (and to explain in your question) what you exactly call a word (an exhaustive list of characters and sequences). Other question, what language do you use?

Comment: I call word the expression `\w*`, and non-word the expression `\W*`, basically. I'm working on PHP/PCRE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use PHP, why you don't convert HTML entities before processing your string with a regex?

Comment: Because HTML entities are optionals, and it should understand that user wants to keep HTML entities as defined, without decode it.

Comment: What the user want isn't important, the only question is what is the best format at the end (for the final use): with or without html entities? Note that you can encode ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ) and decode ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php ). Note too that it is better to do that than describing in your pattern something that looks like an html entity but that eventually doesn't make sense like: `&happyNewYear;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to accomplish your regex match goal as specifically stated. I believe that you'd need a variable width negative lookback to avoid matching unwanted HTML entities, and that doesn't exist in any implementation that I've seen.

But, if your true goal is just to split the strings in the manner you've specified, there are two ways to accomplish that goal.

#### `#1`

You can match and consume the preliminary characters as a group, replacing the original string with just the first group match (`${result}`). `${removed}` will have the text matching the removed characters as you described in your question.

[`^(?<result>.*?(?:(?:&[a-z]+;)|\w)*?)(?<removed>(\W*)((?:&[a-z]+;|\w)*))(?<=.)$`](https://regex101.com/r/oG5hZ4/8) [<kbd>@ regex101</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/oG5hZ4/9)

Since all matches are optional, the trailing `(?<=.)` is present to avoid a matching completely empty lines. I'm also using a simplified definition of HTML entities as you suggested (eg, assuming lowercase and ignoring numeric entities such as "&#60;").

All updated unit tests pass.

#### `#2`

Alternatively, you can reverse the strings and use something like this regex to match the desired characters to remove:

`^(?<removed>((?:;[a-z]+&|\w)*)((?:[^\w;]|;(?![a-z]+&))*))(?<=.)`

Then, after removing the characters, re-reverse the string. `${removed}` will have the characters that were removed (as a reversed string). Note that, as of yet, I've only done some preliminary testing on the "reversed" regex.

Comment: I just thought now that regex should not solves this problem alone (in one expression). Then I changed my engine to consumes words one by one with expressions. It worked now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `\w` because it does not include HTML entities as you point out.

Instead, accept any combination of letters *and* HTML entities, something like this:

`([a-zA-Z]*(&[a-zA-Z]+;)*[a-zA-Z]*)+\s([a-zA-Z]*(&[a-zA-Z]+;)*[a-zA-Z]*)+$`
https://regex101.com/r/pH7tK2/2

Comment: It failed all tests that I defined on *unit tests* tab. But thanks for help.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please post the code of your unit tests, for instance on http://ideone.com so we can run them.